# ARM microcontrollers for robotics

Tags: arm, robotics

I have been working on ARM9 microcontroller LPC3141 until recently, but I am wondering if there are any better and newer ARM microcontrollers more suitable for robotics.

**ADD:**
Are there any general rules on how to choose the right ARM? I mean are families like "cortex", ARM9, ARM11 intended each for a different purpose?

Comment: Have you tried looking on relevant ARM websites to see if there are any "newer ARM microcontrollers more suitable for robotics"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding ARM processor come in in the M series, A series and R series among others. The [M series](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/index.php) is usually for energy efficient Micro-controller type of applications. The [A series](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/index.php) is devoted to more a microprocessor where you are runnning an OS like linux or andriod inteded to run aplication. The [R series](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-r/index.php) is more adequate when Real time performance. 
But choosing which one is the correct for you robotics application depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to create an autonomous vehicle guided by GPS probably it can be done with the M series but if you are looking at computer vision while using that to navigate and create maps of your surrounding you might be stepping in to the realm of the R series or perhaps even x86 architectures